# Error in Terminal - bash: export: `/Users/chrisdutton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin': not a valid identifier

Tags: node.js, ruby, npm, terminal, node-modules

I have updated my OS to Sierra this morning and had all sorts of issues with npm, node etc. I have managed to be able to run grunt and get websites working locally, however I get errors each time I open a new terminal window.

I get the following

```
-bash: export: `/Users/chrisdutton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: uname: command not found
-bash: ps: command not found
chriss-imac:~ chrisdutton$
```

It allows me to run grunt, bower etc and works fine, but something is not right.

```
ruby -v = ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
npm -v = 5.6.0
node -v = v9.4.0
Homebrew 1.4.3

Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
/usr/local/include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_build.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_rules.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
/usr/local/include/node/pthread-fixes.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/classext.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/st.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/util.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/debug.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/defines.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/digest.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/encoding.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/io.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/missing.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/oniguruma.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/re.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/regex.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/st.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/subst.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/thread.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/thread_native.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/util.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/version.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/vm.h
/usr/local/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-darwin11.0/ruby/config.h
/usr/local/include/ublio.h
```